# How in SonataAdminBundle get current admin class?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

How in SonataAdminBundle
get the current admin class without using AdminPool?

Now I'm trying to do it like this

```
    $entityClass = get_class($entity);
    $adminClass = $this->adminPool->getAdminByClass($entityClass);
```

But this method has a problem. If the entity is associated with several classes of the admin, an exception will be thrown.
Is there a way to find out what exactly the admin service should handle the current route?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to say, I need this feature inside Voter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple admins registered for this entity's class, nothing can choose the correct one for you.

You can still get a specific admin with the method `Pool::getAdminByAdminCode(string $code)`.

For example, an usage for you could be:

```
if ($entityClass === MultipleAdminRegisteredEntity::class) {
    $admin = $this->adminPool->getAdminById('specific_admin_id');
} else {
    $entityClass = get_class($entity);
    $admin = $this->adminPool->getAdminByClass($entityClass);
}
```

Please pay attention to the fact that the `Pool::getAdminByClass(string $class)` returns an `Admin` and not a class `string`: you named your variable `$adminClass` which suggests you made this confusion.

Also note that there is an open issue on Github here: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3908 to determine a way to be able define default admins when there are more than one admin for an entity, so that the `Pool:getAdminByClass()` method doesn't throw an exception. Nobody seems to have care enough about this to implement it, feel free to contribute there if you want.